# Is there a way to filter an entity by date, retrieving that date from another table, with an hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hql

This is my first question. I'm sorry if I can't express myself properly.

I have an entity Enterprise. It has a @OneToMany annotation indicating that each Enterprise has a list of Receipts.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="enterprise",
    fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
    targetEntity=Receipt.class, 
    cascade={},
    orphanRemoval=false)
public List<Receipt> getReceiptList() {
    return receiptList;
}
```

The entity receipt has a column 'date' and I need to retrieve each receipt linked to the enterprise between a start_date and an end_date. The problem is that I have those dates (start/end) stored into another table, "accounting_years". So basically I need to give the annotation above the information needed to filter the receipts based on the information i get from the accounting_years table. Please note that at the point where i'm getting the enterprise and the receipts, I already have the info about the accounting_year, so one accounting year is always selected.

Please forgive my awful explanation.
Tell me if I can provide further code, tables or else. Thank you.

Table 'accounting_years'
columns: id, start_date, end_date

Table 'receipts'
columns: id, date, enterprise_id

Table 'enterprise'
columns: id, other columns

Comment: Could you make a SQL `View` from your tables that contains all that information? That's what you you try first

Comment: Of course i could make a view, but i still need to specify the accounting_year.